# load filter after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="submit" style="" id="search" class="fwsubmit btn" value="Submit" name="search">

<div id="FwDvHtmlTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
```

First, I want to filter my search. In my browser it automatically loads the `<div>`. I want to load the contents of my `<div>` after the user clicks the `submit button`. What is the best method to do this? What property can do this?

Comment: you need to give a LOT more details to not have this question closed

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/sAAQZ/ ??

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you go with a simple:

```
$('#search').bind('click', function() {
    // Do whatever is needed
});
```

or

```
$('#myForm').bind('submit', function() {
    // Do whatever is needed
});
```

Comment: 1) use .on 2) don't use .on("click" but .on("submit" of the form or make it a button